# ServiceStack dynamic result set to xml

Tags: xml, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have a problem with two ServiceStack "dynamic" query that basically do the same thing:

```
var results = Db.SqlList<Dictionary<string, object>>("SELECT * FROM TableName");
```

and the Dapper equivalent:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> results = Db.Query("SELECT * FROM TableName");
```

They work right if I request a JSON response but they rise a 500 Server Error (IIS) if I request an XML response.
Which is the difference? Isn't just a different way to present the same data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many serializers do not support `object` or `dynamic` types, which is why mapping them to clean POCO's is always preferred.